# How to set a shell exit trap from within a function in zsh and bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Consider the following shell function:

```
f() {
    echo "function"
    trap 'echo trap; sleep 1' EXIT
}
```

Under bash this will print the following:

```
~$ f
function
~$ exit
trap
```

On zsh however this is the result:

```
~$ f
function
trap
~$ exit
```

This is as explained in the [zshbuiltins man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins):

> If sig is 0 or EXIT and the trap statement is executed inside the body of a function, then the command arg is executed after the function completes.

My question: Is there a way of setting an `EXIT` trap that only executes on **shell exit** in *both* bash and zsh?

Comment: Not in a place where I can test, but what if you define a global trap outside functions and then redefine whatever it calls inside your function? Like `trap '$t' EXIT; f() { t='echo trap; sleep 1' }` or perhaps more elegantly by redefining a function?

Comment: Interesting idea, but that would mean unconditionally setting up an exit trap (even if it's just en empty function) - does feel a bit "hackish".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obligatory boring and uninteresting answer:

```
f() { 
  if [ "$ZSH_VERSION" ]
  then
    zshexit() { echo trap; sleep 1; }  # zsh specific
  else
    trap 'echo trap; sleep 1' EXIT     # POSIX
  fi
}
```

Comment: I actually want the opposite of this, for the trap ("finally" clause) to be only within the function. ZSH supports this, not sure about Bash.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai According to [Bash builtin manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) you can trap `RETURN` instead. It is even better than `EXIT` in Zsh: the Bash `RETURN` trap will be triggered even if you terminated the function with `SIGINT`.